# Java parallelization using lambda functions

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing

I have an array of some objects with the method process() that I want to run parallelized. And I wanted to try lambdas to achieve the parallelization. So I tried this:

```
Arrays.asList(myArrayOfItems).forEach(item->{
    System.out.println("processing " + item.getId());
    item.process();
});
```

Each process() call takes about 2 seconds. And I have noticed that there is still no speedup with the "parallelization" approach. It seems that everything is still running serialized. The ids are printed in series (ordered) and between every print there is a pause of 2 seconds.

Probably I have misunderstood something. What is needed to execute this in parallel using lambdas (hopefully in a very condensed way)?

Comment: did you mean `.parallelStream().forEach(item -> {..`

Comment: Thank you, parallelStream() solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas itself aren't executing anything in parallel. `Stream`s are capable of doing this though.

Take a look at the method `Collection#parallelStream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--)):

```
Arrays.asList(myArrayOfItems).parallelStream().forEach(...);
```

However, note that there is no guarantee or control when it will actually go parallel. From its documentation:

> Returns a **possibly parallel** Stream with this collection as its source. It is **allowable** for this method to **return a sequential stream**.

The reason is simple. You really need **a lot** of elements in your collection (like millions) for parallelization to actually pay off (or doing other heavy things). The overhead introduced with parallelization is **huge**. Because of that, the method might choose to use sequential stream instead, if it thinks that it will be faster.

Before you think about using parallelism, you should actually setup some benchmarks to test if it improves anything. There are many examples where people did just blindly use it without noticing that they actually decreased the perfomance. Also see [Should I always use a parallel stream when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible).

---

You can check if a `Stream` is parallel by using `Stream#isParallel` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#isParallel--)).

If you use `Stream#parallel` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#isParallel--)) directly on a stream, you get a parallel version.

Comment: I think this would be the best answer, altough it has one flaw: When each operation takes 2 seconds it really pays off on a much lower amount of ops than millions when a user is looking for a fluid experience.

Comment: That is correct. Just note that parallelism introduces a huge overhead and you shouldn't blindly use it everywhere without thinking about it or actually measuring times.

Answer (score 1):

Method Collection.forEach() is just iteration through all the elements. It is called **internal iteration** as it leaves up to the collection *how* it will iterate, but it is still an iteration on all the elements.

If you want parallel processing, you have to:

1. Get a parallel stream from the collection.
2. Specify the operation(s) which will be done on the stream.
3. Do something with the result if you need to.

You may read first part of my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942829/2886891

Answer (score 1):

To create a parallel stream, invoke the operation `.parallelStream` on a Collection

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

```
Arrays.asList(myArrayOfItems).parallelStream().forEach(item->{
    System.out.println("processing " + item.getId());
    item.process();
});
```