# Why have multiple version of Optional in Java 8

Tags: java-8, option-type

I noticed that, There are multiple versions of many Types in Java 8.

For example, The introduced [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class has many flavors of [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html), `OptionalLong` etc..

Although the `Optional` has a type Parameter (`Optional<T>`), we still need some specific types for primitives, Why?

I cannot find a BIG difference between the following:

```
Optional<Integer> o = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 5).stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).findAny();
System.out.println(o.orElse(-1));

OptionalInt oi = Arrays.stream(new int[] { 1, 3, 6, 5 }).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).findAny();
System.out.println(oi.orElse(-1));
```

Comment: The BIG difference you're looking for is *performance*.

Comment: How?And Why not in other parts we see such convention?

Comment: You ask *how* is a primitive faster than a wrapper object? In other parts of the JDK they weren't paying as much attention to performance. But when you do a feature whose key benefit is performance, you have another story.

Comment: There is nothing special about specialisation for primitive types. Take a look at `java.util.Arrays` and you will see, that basically every algorithm exists 8 times. In contrast, _Optional_ only exists four times.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22919112/697630) may add more details to your quest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's true that `Optional<Integer>` behaves quite similar to `OptionalInt` from a functional point of view. For example, there is no functional difference between the following to methods:

```
int foo(int value) {
    return OptionalInt.of(value).orElse(4242);
}
int bar(int value) {
    return Optional.of(value).orElse(4242);
}
```

However, there can be a difference in performance and efficiency--depending on how the optional types are used and on the capabilities of the JIT compiler. The second method is basically identical to the following method:

```
int baz(int value) {
    return Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(value))
        .orElse(Integer.valueOf(4242))
        .intValue();
}
```

As you can see, due to auto-boxing for each method call up to two additional Integer objects will be created. Compared to native types, the creation of an object is expensive, and each additional object increases the pressure on the garbage collection.

That doesn't mean, that it will make a difference for most applications. But it can make a difference, and if it's not there, it lowers the acceptance for Java 8 Streams.