# Is Java 8 missing an OptionalBoolean?

Tags: java, boolean, monads, java-8, option-type

As a primitive version of [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)*, Java 1.8 provides [`OptionalInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html), [`OptionalLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalLong.html) and [`OptionalDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html).

But I cannot find the equivalent `OptionalBoolean` class.

Are there any technical reasons against having an `OptionalBoolean`?

*
*An `Optional` may or may not have the presence of a value, is used as an alternative to `null`.*

Comment: I suppose we could ask the same question about why `OptionalChar`, `OptionalByte`, `OptionalShort`, and `OptionalFloat` are also missing.

Comment: I *definitely* remember reading something about this. If memory serves, it had to do with the fact that everything "fits" into an `int`, `long`, and `double`, so the other ones would be redundant.

Comment: I was just thinking that `OptionalInt` "kind of" covers for `OptionalByte`, `OptionalShort`,  and `OptionalChar`. The `int` in a `OptionalInt` might overflow on the client side, but in every day code authorship, we are used to making these conversions. Not as much though going from an `int` to a `boolean`. I would very much like to see a `OptionalBoolean`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918847/why-are-new-java-util-arrays-methods-in-java-8-not-overloaded-for-all-the-primit) is related.

Comment: @Eran That's what I was searching for! Brian Goetz's quote answers this question perfectly.

Comment: That is it. If you google the text for "Trick #1", you'll find what I would accept as an answer to my question, that it was a tradeof made to keep the type explosion down to a minimum. One of you should add an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @user3580294 Well, the quote is about primitive streams, but I assume the same logic applied to primitive Optionals.

Comment: owlstead, I don't believe any question can have a definitive answer. But I see your point.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/28738297/57695

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This quote explains the considerations behind having primitive streams. I'm assuming the same applied to primitive Optionals. In short, primitive streams (and probably Optionals as well) were created for performance reasons. They didn't create them for all 8 primitive types to reduce code duplication and interface pollution.

Quoting the words of Brian Goetz in the [lambda mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006750.html):

> More generally: the philosophy behind having specialized
>   primitive streams (e.g., IntStream) is fraught with nasty tradeoffs.
>   On the one hand, it's lots of ugly code duplication, interface
>   pollution, etc. On the other hand, any kind of arithmetic on boxed ops
>   sucks, and having no story for reducing over ints would be terrible.
>   So we're in a tough corner, and we're trying to not make it worse.
>
> Trick #1 for not making it worse is: we're not doing all eight
>   primitive types. We're doing int, long, and double; all the others
>   could be simulated by these. Arguably we could get rid of int too, but
>   we don't think most Java developers are ready for that. Yes, there
>   will be calls for Character, and the answer is "stick it in an int."
>   (Each specialization is projected to ~100K to the JRE footprint.)
>
> Trick #2 is: we're using primitive streams to expose things that are best done in the primitive domain (sorting, reduction) but not
>   trying to duplicate everything you can do in the boxed domain. For
>   example, there's no IntStream.into(), as Aleksey points out. (If there
>   were, the next question(s) would be "Where is IntCollection?
>   IntArrayList? IntConcurrentSkipListMap?) The intention is many streams
>   may start as reference streams and end up as primitive streams, but
>   not vice versa. That's OK, and that reduces the number of conversions
>   needed (e.g., no overload of map for int -> T, no specialization of
>   Function for int -> T, etc.)

And I should mention that I found that quote in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918847/why-are-new-java-util-arrays-methods-in-java-8-not-overloaded-for-all-the-primit).

Comment: Just be patient for Java 9.

Comment: "Each specialization is projected to ~100K to the JRE footprint." This probably holds for streams; I'd expect an `Optional` to have a smaller footprint.

Answer (score 7):

`boolean` values are often abused as parameters. Effective Java 2nd edition warns against abuse of booleans. They often lead to badly readable code if they are not for actual boolean true/false arguments. Instead, Joshua Bloch - the writer - tries to convince people to use double valued `enum`'s:

> **Prefer two-element `enum` types to `boolean` parameters**. It makes your code easier to read and to write, especially if you're using an IDE that supports autocompletion. Also it makes it easy to add more options later.

Most `OptionalBoolean` instances would probably be used incorrectly. This is a good reason for not including one. But I cannot say - only Oracle can - if this is the reason why it is not in there.

Comment: So has it become Oracle's policy to omit language features that might possibly be misused?  Kind of disappointing, although I don't care specifically about the absence of OptionalBoolean.  It's just as well that the makers of machine language didn't have such a policy - we'd have just 0s and no 1s.

Comment: I love that book, and I respect Joshua very much. I also think you have a point. When Joshua described good ways of overriding and implementing `Object.equals(Object)` in that book, he said that one must always use the `instanceof` operator and called the use of `getClass()` for being "unacceptable" (page 39). I've also noticed that all library code in Oracle's implementation is using the `instanceof` operator. I haven't found one example of the `getClass()` operator (which happens to be my favorite in non-library code). So a quote from Joshua on the topic would be really valuable.

Comment: I agree with you, and I do prefer `enum` over `boolean` values as "options" to a method call. What I would need is a tri-state boolean though, one that can represent an "any" or "inconclusive" state. And I hate nulls ever since Java 1.8 =)

Comment: @owlstead Checked exceptions anyone?

Comment: @Eran up on the question comments found another question whose accepted answer would likely answer this question. tl;dr: [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006750.html)

Answer (score 3):

Apart for the desire to reduce the magnitude of the combinatorial explosion of primitive type specialisation classes I suspect one major reason for the absence of an `OptionalBoolean` is that the advantage of such a class is much smaller than the advantage of specialisations for the numeric types.

The reason for why the advantage is smaller is that there are only two different values of the type `boolean`. Because of this, most of the time you only get two object of type `Boolean`. Those two are cached as `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` and reused in most cases, e.g. when `boolean`s are auto-boxed. Numeric wrapper types have a number of cached objects for a small range of values, for other values a new object has to be allocated every time a primitive value is stored in a generic container such as `Optional`.

So an `Optional<Boolean>` object is almost as efficient as an `OptionalBoolean` would be since no new `Boolean` have to be allocated to put an unboxed `boolean` into it.

I could also be useful to have two cashed `Optional<Boolean>` available somewhere in the standard library, as `Optional.TRUE/FALSE` perhaps. I don't know the reason for why there isn't.

Comment: `Boolean` will not be allocated, but `Optional<T>` will be. Compared with `OptionalBoolean` implementation, which can be implemented as an enum of `{oTrue, oFalse, none}`, this still would have bigger memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be complete about that: There is indeed an `OptionalBoolean` in Java 8, but not where you would expect it: it is `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.OptionalBoolean`.

But, while JavaFX is nowadays a fixed component of Java, it is not advisable to use it outside of JavaFX stuff.

Apart from that, its interface is completely different from the ones you have in `java.util.*`.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a comment instead, but whatever it is, it's definitely a good warning for those relying on completion in IDE's such as Eclipse, NetBeans and similar.