# Why isn't this lambda a singular object?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Simply, I'm trying to iterate over an array using a stream to find out if every element is the same type of object. I have figured out two ways of doing this (`foo` is a byte array `byte[]`).

```
Arrays.asList(foo).parallelStream().allMatch(aByte -> aByte == Byte.MIN_VALUE);
```

and

```
Stream.of(foo).parallel().allMatch(aByte -> aByte == Byte.MIN_VALUE);
```

However, I keep getting the error `"Incompatible operand types byte[] and byte"`. So that means that `aByte` is of type `byte[]`. Why is that? Why is it not just a normal `byte`? And how may I correct this problem?

Comment: They have `IntStream.of(int...)`, but there's no `ByteStream` :) ...

Comment: Convert `foo` to a `Byte[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `foo` is of type `byte[]`, then `Arrays.asList(foo)` will return a list containing a single element: `foo`.

It would return a list containing all the elements of `foo` is foo was an array of Objects. But it's not, because byte is a primitive type, not an Object. And a byte[] is thus not an Object[].

What you should use in fact is an `IntStream`. See [What is the best way to convert a byte array to an IntStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810251/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-intstream) for how to convert a byte array to an IntStream.

Note that using a parallel stream for such a simple task is not a good idea. Unless the byte array is awfully huge and contains only Byte.MIN_VALUE, the overhead of a parallel stream over a sequential one will make things slower.