# java.util.Arrays.toString method is not overloaded for Strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I've been programming in Scala since 2010 (it's the end of 2017 now) and was shocked today to find out that the `java.util.Arrays.toString` method is not overloaded for `String`s. The following works as expected in Java, but not in Scala.

**Java**

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
  }
}
```

**Scala**

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args))
  }
}
```

I know many workarounds for this (so no need to suggest any), but I would assume I wouldn't need one in the first place. I can neither imagine this being a bug (or rather an unfinished feature) for so many years nor can I imagine this behavior being intended.

```
<console>:12: error: overloaded method value toString with alternatives:
  (x$1: Array[Object])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Double])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Float])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Boolean])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Byte])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Char])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Short])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Int])String <and>
  (x$1: Array[Long])String
 cannot be applied to (Array[String])
```

Can someone come up with a reasonable explanation why this is not working? Please don't be cheeky, I see that it's not overloaded for `String`s, but there is clearly some hack in Java to make it work, why is there none in Scala?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918847/why-are-new-java-util-arrays-methods-in-java-8-not-overloaded-for-all-the-primit), but again it works in Java, why doesn't it in Scala?

PS

Not that it matters, but I got:

- Scala v2.12.4
- Java v1.8.0_151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a bug in java that it works. If you look at the list of candidates, you'll see, that clearly there is no suitable alternative. It ends up calling `Array[Object]` variant by accident, but that is wrong, becuase `Array` is invariant in its type parameter (all generic types are invariant in java), so `Array[Object]` is *not* a superclass of `Array[String]`.

Comment: This is not true. [Arrays are covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666878/1349366) in Java.

Comment: @Aivean ok, I'll rephrase: it is a bug, that arrays are covariant in java. :) They really shouldn't be. Consider this: `void foo(Object[] a) { a[0] = "foo"; }`
and then `foo(new Integer[] {0});` This compiles without warning (because of the same bug), and then crashes at run time.

Comment: I think a better way to look at it is: arrays are really invariant, but the compiler lets you treat them as covariant, which seems like a bug (or rather a (semi-intentional) flaw in the implementation). That's what I tried to convey in my answer.

Comment: ok, so, to conclude, for legacy reasons in Java arrays are covariant, and `Arrays.toString` relies on that. In scala `Array` variance is fixed (it's invariant), so java's `toString(Array[AnyRef])` can no longer be used with `Array[String]`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thx for the explanation.