# How to use lambda expression with byte array in Java?

Tags: java, lambda

I have a variable of type `byte[]`, not `Byte[]`.

I'm trying to use `Arrays::stream` method to process this array with lambda.

However, there's no such reload of `Arrays::stream` that takes `byte[]` as parameter.

The reload `Arrays::stream(T[] data)` also does not work. 
I guess it's because byte[] is an array of java prime type byte, which cannot be treated as generic type parameter `T`.

I tried to cast `byte[]` to `Byte[]` or `int[]`, which all failed as well.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? maybe you don't need streams at all.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32459683/2513200

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22918847/2513200

Answer (score 6):

You can create an `IntStream`:

```
byte[] bytearr = new byte[10];
IntStream ints = IntStream.range (0, bytearr.length).map (i->bytearr[i]);
```

or a `Stream<Byte>`:

```
byte[] bytearr = new byte[10];
Stream<Byte> bytes = IntStream.range (0, bytearr.length).mapToObj (i->bytearr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is no `ByteStream` in java, there is only `Stream<T>`, `IntStream`, `DoubleStream` and `LongStream`.

Just do this with normal loops, unless you want to implement that class manually.
Or you can convert that to `Byte[]` but this will be huge waste of time and memory. Same with converting to `int[]` and using `IntStream`, but smaller cost than `Byte[]`.

But there is no reason to do something like that unless you are forced to do this that way, it might affect performance and memory footprint a lot for bigger arrays.