# Arrays.stream() for byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

Java 8 introduced [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to convert a (primitive) array to a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

How can this method be used to get a stream for a `byte[]`?

---

It looks like the method only exists for `double[]`, `int[]` and `long[]`, but not for `byte[]`.

[image: Arrays.stream() methods]

I guess the reason is that `Arrays.stream()` internally utilizes `StreamSupport` which does not provide a method for `byte[]` ...

Comment: Interesting related SO question: "Why are new java.util.Arrays methods in Java 8 not overloaded for all the primitive types?" https://stackoverflow.com/q/22918847/1518225

Answer (score 2):

You can create an IntStream using `map`

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
IntStream byteStream = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length).map(i -> bytes[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it like this. Index the array via an `IntStream` and then return a boolean depending on the presence of the value.

```
boolean v = IntStream.range(0, demoArray.length).map(i -> demoArray[i])
    .filter(i -> i == 0x42).findFirst().isPresent();

System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
true
```

Or as [Youcef Laidani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/youcef-laidani) kindly pointed out use `anyMatch`.

```
boolean v = IntStream.range(0, demoArray.length).map(i -> demoArray[i])
    .anyMatch(i -> i == 0x42);
```

Comment: …and even shorter `boolean v = IntStream.range(0, demoArray.length) .anyMatch(i -> demoArray[i] == 0x42);`

Answer (score 1):

Since I needed the `byte[]` stream only for `anyMatch()`, I came up with the following snippet as "quick fix":

```java
private static boolean anyMatch(byte[] data, Predicate<Byte> predicate) {
  for(byte d : data) {
     if(predicate.test(d)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

To be called like this:

```java
byte[] demoArray new byte[]{0x1, 0x2, 0x42};
boolean exists = anyMatch(demoArray, i -> i == 0x42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you still can do Arrays.stream on Objects of type T

so all you need to do is converting byte[] into Byte[].

To convert byte[] into Byte[] you basically need to do foreach loop and convert each byte into Byte or you can use apache lang3 utils

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[100];
Byte[] byteObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(byteArray);
Stream<Byte> byteObjectStream = Arrays.stream(byteObjectArray);
```